# "Regular points" and "Vector grid" don't work for me in QGIS 2.18.4

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.18

I have a QGIS 2.18.4. I wanted to use "regular points" feature, but whenever I try QGIS gets stuck at the beginning
[image]

Nothing happens afterward.

The same thing happens with another research tool: "vector grid".

I have no issues with other QGIS components, except this two.

Is there anything I can try, except of uninstalling QGIS and trying another version?

Comment: It would help if you show a picture of the parameters dialogue. For vector grid, make sure the spacing is something useful, like 10000 meters when using a projected CRS.

Comment: You're right. Having wider spacing fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Pleasse self-answer your question for the benefit of future visitors.